# How can I set each server their unique welcome channel? Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a welcome message! Except I am having a problem! Each server has their own unique welcome channel! How do I make a setup code in order for each server to send in a welcome message in their unique welcome channels?

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#Client
client = discord.Client()

#Prefix
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

x = 'welcome'

#Custom Status
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name=x)
    await channel.send("Test")




client.run('MY TOKEN')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this isn't your question, but I would like to point this out. You need to use either `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot`. Note that `commands.Bot` has all the attributes of `discord.Client`.

Now, to allow each server to have their own welcome channels, you'll have to store the server ids of the servers, and their corresponding welcome channel's ids in a `.json` file or a database. If you're building a bot for small number of servers, a json file is good to use, else I would recommend a database.